# Images are shown delayed after app start

Tags: image, sencha-touch-2, delay

I developed an app with Sencha Touch 2 and use images on different views (with `xtype: 'image'`)

When I start the app on my iPhone, the image is shown round about half to one second later than all other elements like buttons or text boxes. This looks very non-professional.

What can I do?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: the images are inside the bundle or loading remotely ? :)

Answer (score 0):

If images are remote then it will show up once all the bytes are transferred from internet so if you want to show everything together you can keep everything else `hidden` at the time of construction of view and use `image` event [load](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.1.1/#!/api/Ext.Img-event-load) to set hidden=false  for other items in that view.